# Faulty review audit?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just got served [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6498220) which shows a post "recently made" by a "new user" to a very popular question posted 22 days ago. To get some more context, I clicked on the question link to see some of the other answers, and the top, and accepted, answer was by Jon Skeet.

I simply assumed this was a new user who made an error and copied Jon's answer as his own and flagged it for moderator attention with the message "This looks like a copy of Jon Skeet's answer", after which I was presented with this rather harsh message:

[image: audit message]

Who's at fault here? The audit system, or should I have understood that it was the audit system trying to fool me and just moved along?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system is working fine, you interpreted the situation wrong.

The review system doesn't ask to check if an answer is copy-pasted. It always asks you to look at only *one* post at a time, independent of other posts on the same page. If you see a good answer and can prove that it's copy-pasted, go to the link and flag for moderator attention, *outside* the review queues.

It's good to flag if a user copy-pastes someone else's answer, but here that wasn't the case.

Comment: I should add: When presented with such an audit, it's presented as if a newly registered user with no reputation has just posted it. Even I understand that you can't duplicate Jon Skeet.

Comment: @jurgemaister My bad, forgot for a moment that the review system hides the user card. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still new to the reviewing business.